# ¿Cómo hacer una llamada recursiva correcta por cada fichero en la ruta?

Tags: bash, recursión, tar

Estoy intentando hacer una función recursiva que dado una ruta inicial comprime todos los archivos en ese nivel(solo los archivos, no las carpetas) usando tar, y en repite el proceso por cada carpeta recursivamente.

```
function recorredor(){
    for i in "$*"/*;
    do
        if [[ -d "$i" ]];
        then
            cd "$i";
            recorredor "$*"/"$i"
            cd "$*";
        else
            if [ -f "d.tar" ]; then
            tar --remove-files -rf d.tar "$i"
            else
        tar --remove-files -cf d.tar "$i"
        fi
    fi
done

}


recorredor .
```

Funciona la compresión para la primera ruta, pero al meterse en una carpeta para repetir da este error

> tar ././carpeta/*: no se puede hacer stat: la carpeta no existe

No sé cómo solucionar este problema, cualquier consejo es bienvenido.

Comment: ¿cómo lo ejecutas? ¿qué jerarquía de ficheros tiene? ¿por qué el hardcode de "d.tar"?

Comment: -Lo ejecuto poniendolo en la carpeta que quiero organizar y ejecutandolo con bash recorredor.sh
-Carpeta es la única carpeta del directorio donde lo estoy ejecutando
-Porque se me ocurrió en ese momento

Answer (score 0):

Encontré varias cuestiones sobre moverse varias veces en direcciones que se traslapan, como `./.` debido al `$*` que utilizas, o el moverse varias veces al salir de la llamada recursiva.

También me tomé el atrevimiento de nombrar las variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

recorredor() {

    declare nombre_archivo="respaldo.tar"
    declare ruta="$1"

    for item in "$ruta"/*
    do
        if [[ -d $item ]]
        then
            cd $item
            recorredor $item
        else
            [[ ! "$item" =~ *($nombre_archivo)* ]] && tar -rf "$nombre_archivo" "$item"
        fi
    done    

}

declare ruta="$1"

[[ $ruta == "." ]] && ruta=$PWD

recorredor "$ruta"
```

La forma de ejecutar este archivo es:

```
$ ./archivo <ruta>
```

Puede ser incluso el punto `$ ./archivo .`

Solo que en la última recursión te añadirá el propio script. Aún no sé como arreglarlo más que poniendo otra restricción en la expresión regular. Pero esto no se oye como a la mejor opción.